# SQL: Selecting One Row When Duplicate IDs

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
FKID1   FKID2   A    
3   40297    3 
3   40297    5 
3   40325    9 
3   40325    8 
3   40325    1 
3   40348    1  
3   40391    2 
3   40392    7 
3   40501    5 
3   40501    4
```

I need a query to result the following table:

```
FKID1   FKID2   A    
3   40297    5 
3   40325    9  
3   40348    1  
3   40391    2 
3   40392    7 
3   40501    5
```

so it chooses only 1 FKID2 from duplicates, and it chooses the one with the max(A) associated with it.

I couldn't do it, so your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
select FKID1, FKID2, max(a)
from yourTable
group by FKID1, FKID2
```

You need group by, and apply an aggregate function.
Read more about this [here](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-aggregate.htm). Also, are more tutorials about this clause on Internet

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that when you use `AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS`, don't forget to add `GROUP BY` clause or else you will have exactly one value. try this one,

```
SELECT FKID1, FKID2, MAX(A) maxValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY FKID1, FKID2
```

if you don't want `FKID1` to show on the result,

```
SELECT FKID2, MAX(A) maxValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY  FKID2
```